# My JS doesn't work when i add jquery to my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I am doing a script JS in Symfony with encore and yarn, when I don't use jquery and never require him my JS is working normally. But at the moment I add jquery with `const $ = require('jquery')` for example my script doesn't work and I got no error messages.

I try to comment `.enableSingleRuntimeChunk()`, add jquery with CDN, try on another project. Nothing change.

```
//base.html.twig
{% block javascripts %}
            <script src="{{ asset('build/runtime.js') }}"></script>
            <script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

```
// Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to require it.
const $ = require('jquery');

console.log('hello');
```

````
Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')

    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images'
    })


    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.fontawesome) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('main', './assets/js/main.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabel(() => {}, {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    .enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

```


I got nothing.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In webpack.config.js try using:

```
.autoProvidejQuery()
```

uncomment (if you have commented)

```
.enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
```

and remove

```
.autoProvidejQuery({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
})
```

In app.js comment `//const $ = require('jquery');` and use jquery

In base.html.twig use

```
{% block javascripts %}
       {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

finally run `yarn encore dev` (for dev env) or  `yarn encore prod` (for prod env) and reload page

Comment: I use it like in docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#configuring-encore-webpack

Comment: No problem! I have also seen this syntax in other questions

Comment: Thank you ! Buona sera !